# How to reduce cpu utilization by background processes?

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have a shell script This script calls another script which is executed in background. However this script which is running in background increases CPU utilization.
My task is to reduce CPU utilization. Please help. How can we fork a process through a shell script ?? 
I have tried nohup, & commands

Example: -

Parent_script.sh executes child_script.sh & (in background)
This child_script.sh increases CPU utilization

NOTE: -child_script.sh has to compulsorily run in background, no alternative to that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`nice`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) command to reduce the priority of a process.

For example, to run a script with the lowest priority you can run:

```
nice -n 9 child_script.sh &
```

Note that this will only work if your machine has got several processes which are demanding more resources that the CPU can provide. If, on the other hand, your machine is idle, then even the lowest priority process can get up to 99% CPU.

If you want to limit the cpu usage of a process even when there is CPU available on the machine, take a look at the [`cpulimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... What if i don't want to reduce the priority ? Is there any alternative still??

Comment: Find out why it is using so much CPU and tune the script.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but cpu utilization has still not reduced.

Comment: The CPU utilization of parent script is high because of the the child process it is exeecuting in the background, The parent script is tuned to a great extent ..

Answer (score 0):

Another way to limit resources is by the use of WLM (Work Load Manager). You can allocate all processes into different classes. Every class will get a priority and a share of processor power. You can dynamically increase or decrease the amount of processing power of a specific class. The default class contains the processes used by AIX.

To be able to decrease the processing power of the child_script.sh based on the contents of the script (what kind of commands you run inside the script) I need to see the contents.